# Output at the same time {parse_mode: 'HTML'} and buttons

Tags: node.js, telegram-bot, node-telegram-bot-api

Friends. Tell me, please: how to display both buttons and {parse_mode: 'HTML'} through node-telegram-bot-api on Node JS?

```
bot.sendMessage(chatId, `${msg.from.first_name}, <b>Hello!</b> ✌ `, {parse_mode: 'HTML', menuOptions})
```

But the telegram bot gives out only bold text, without buttons.

Swapped parse_mode: 'HTML' and menuOptions. I put menuOptions after the curly braces - the result did not change. I couldn't find the info I needed on google.

Answer (score 0):

With inline keyboard:

```js
  bot.sendMessage(msg.chat.id, "<b>bold</b> <i>italic</i>", {
    parse_mode: "HTML",
    reply_markup: {
      inline_keyboard: [
        [
          {
            text: 'Google',
            url: 'https://google.com'
          }
        ]
      ]
    }
  })
```

With normal keyboard:

```js
  bot.sendMessage(msg.chat.id, "<b>bold</b> <i>italic</i>", {
    parse_mode: "HTML",
    reply_markup: {
      keyboard: [
        ['A'],
        ['B']
      ]
    }
  })
```

Comment: And if I have buttons in a separate file, can I display them in this message with the "menuOptions" variable or not?

Comment: Yes you can, it just has to follow the same JSON format above.

Comment: It matches. But when I do:
`bot.sendMessage(msg.chat.id, "<b>bold</b> <i>italic</i>", {
    parse_mode: "HTML",
    reOptions})`
it doesn't work.
Code reOptions:
`reOptions: {
        reply_markup: JSON.stringify({
            inline_keyboard: [
                [{text: 'Назад', callback_data: '/re'}]
            ]
        })
    },`